# SQL update foreign key conflicted

Tags: c#, sql

It's giving me an UPDATE error while trying to update the foreign's key value

SQL Query

```
data = "UPDATE Reservations SET id_room = @idRoom FROM Reservations WHERE id_reservation = @idReservation";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(data, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idRoom", idRoom);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idReservation", idReservationTxtBox.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

[SQL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBXmE.png)

[SQL Reservations table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvvaH.png)

[SQL Rooms table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHtO5.png)

[Reservations table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywdUO.png)

[Rooms table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLNdh.png)

[idRoom variable definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYILQ.png)

SQL Reservations table BUT IN CODE

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reservations] (
    [id_reservation]  INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [n_card]          VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
    [cardholder_name] TEXT         NOT NULL,
    [expiration_date] DATE         NOT NULL,
    [cvc]             VARCHAR (3)  NOT NULL,
    [id_room]         INT          NOT NULL,
    [reserva_price]   FLOAT (53)   NOT NULL,
    [check-in]        DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [check-out]       DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Reservas] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id_reservation] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Reservations_Rooms] FOREIGN KEY ([id_room]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Rooms] ([id_room])
);
```

SQL Rooms table BUT IN CODE

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms] (
    [id_room]   INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [n_room]    INT  NOT NULL,
    [type_room] TEXT NOT NULL,
    [available] BIT  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Rooms] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id_room] ASC)
);
```

I tried to find the error on google but it didn't show any results

I was expecting to update the table Reservations by changing the id_room to the value on the code which is (idRoom)

Comment: A you sure the record with specified `Rooms.id_room` exists?

Comment: What is the value of `idRoom`?

Comment: Always verify queries in SQL Server Management Studio before testing in c#.  Error messages are much better in SSMS.  Error could indicate the primary key is not in database so you have to use Insert Instead of Update. ExecuteNonQuery returns an integer indicating number of rows that changed.   You can check the log files in SSMQ in explorer under management which will give better indication of error.

Comment: @Alexander yes there is a id_room in the Rooms table

Comment: @jdweng u want me to edit the question and show u if there's an error message on SSMS?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock the valueof the idRoom is a SelectedValue of a combobox which is the name the id of the room that gets it from the database

Comment: What is the "actual" value?

Comment: btw I'm sorry reservations is a table sry guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a constraint set up that prohibits inserting an ID into the `Reservations` table's `id_room` column that does not exist in `reservations_rooms`.

The value of `@idRoom` that you are inserting into `Reservations` needs to exist as a record (PK) in the `reservations_rooms` table.

Based on your added screenshots in the Original Question, you can only "insert" values of (1, 2 or 3) in the `id_room` column, as that is the only rows that exist in the `reservations_rooms` table.

Comment: how to I change that prohibitation and how do I create the PK to the reservations table?

Comment: Show your data that you have for the `reservations_rooms` table, and the ID (@idRoom) value that you are trying to use in your update query.

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question with the data you're asking

Comment: See my update on the answer.

Comment: exactly that's what i want and after the selected value is get I do another query that gets the id_room where the number of the room is the one where is selected on the combo box

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: basically I have a combo box which it's items are the numbers of the rooms that are available on the database on the Rooms table and when one item is selected supposedly it was supposed to update the reservation to be more exact, the id_room and there's where the variable idRoom appears, that is a SELECT id_room based on the selectedvalue of the combo box and the problem is what is on the original question

Comment: What is an "actual" value that you insert (get from combobox), that you are trying to use for @idRoom ?

Comment: the id of the number of the room selected in the combo box

Comment: Read my question again. I cant debug your combobox on here, debug your sql insert code and find what the actual value is that you are trying to use...

Comment: oh sorry let's take as an example that he chooses 105 on the combobox so the value of idRoom is 2

Comment: 2 should work.. are you "sure" it is 2, or do you "think" it's 2. Did you debug your code?

Comment: I did by a fact I put a messagebox as a debug to tell me what was the idRoom and it shows me 2

Comment: nvm it's getting 0 for some reason

Comment: That would be your problem. Sort that out so you get a relevant "id" from the`reservations_rooms` table, and your update query should work.